# Filter extended event xml_deadlock_report by database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock, extended-events

I have added an extended event log that logs `blocked_process_report` events and `xml_deadlock_report` events.

I can exclude certain databases from the blocked_process_report by adding `WHERE ([database_name]<>N'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')`.

But how do I exclude a database's `xml_deadlock_report` events? The property "`sqlserver.database_name`" appears to be set to "`master`" for a deadlock event, no matter where the deadlock occured. I suppose this is because in theory multiple databases could be affected by the same deadlock.

[image]

The server in question contains a database which constantly has deadlocks, but which is managed by a different entity and does not concern me. I would like to prevent these events from filling up the log.

This is the script used to create the log:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [blocked_process] ON SERVER 

ADD EVENT sqlserver.blocked_process_report(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([database_name]<>N'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')),

ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report(
    ACTION(package0.callstack,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.username)) 

ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'D:\xxx\blocked_process.xel',max_file_size=(65536),max_rollover_files=(5),metadatafile=N'D:\xxx\blocked_process.xem')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)   May 14 2014 18:34:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

SSMS: `13.0.16106.4`

I can create a filter for deadlock without any error.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [blocked_process] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.blocked_process_report(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([database_name]<>N'test')),

ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report(
    ACTION(package0.callstack,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]<>N'test'))

ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'c:\blocked_process.xel',max_file_size=(65536),max_rollover_files=(5),metadatafile=N'c:\blocked_process.xem')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Here is the picture where I am adding filter (if I am using GUI).
[image]

Comment: The problem is that the swlserver.database_name for a deadlock event is not the affected database. For all the deadlocks I found in the log, the database_name is set to 'master', even if the affected tables are in a different database.

Comment: (I have updated the question with a screenshot; sorry, my original question was not clear in this regard)